# Reduce unnecessary duplication between two classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, code-duplication

I have two classes responsible for attributes validation:

```
class NameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t('errors.attributes.name.invalid'))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless NameValidator.valid_name?(value)
  end

  def self.valid_name?(name)
    name =~ /\A[a-z][\w\p{Blank}]+\z/i
  end
end
```

and the second one

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t('errors.attributes.email.invalid'))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless EmailValidator.valid_email?(value)
  end

  def self.valid_email?(email)
    email =~ /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i
  end
end
```

They're basically the same. Should I inherit them from one class with protected utility methods or what?

Comment: IMHO this would be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this further

```
class PatternValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message) || kind
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless value =~ validation_pattern
  end
end

class NameValidator < PatternValidator
  def validation_pattern; /\A[a-z][\w\p{Blank}]+\z/i end
end

class EmailValidator < PatternValidator
  def validation_pattern; /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i end
end
```

EachValidator has a #kind method so it will add :name or :email as the failure message unless overridden. Then you can leave the i18n to do the lookup as per the standard cascade as documented in [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance only when one class is clearly a special case of another. In your example, it seems that the two classes are equal. Then, use mixin, and not inheritance.

A minor point in your code that stands against commonizing `validate_each` is the hardcoding of `NameValidator.valid_name?` and `EmailValidator.valid_email?`. You need to make them the same in the common code to be used in both classes. First of all, you don't need to give different names `valid_name?` and `valid_email?`. Their differences should be absorbed by the use of the respective classes. Use a common name. Second, you don't need to hard code the receiver. Instead, use `self.class`. But rather than doing that using class methods, use an instance method.

```
module ValidatorModule
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t("errors.attributes.#{attribute}.invalid"))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless valid?(value)
  end
end

class NameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  include ValidatorModule
  def attribute; "name" end
  def valid?(value); value =~ /\A[a-z][\w\p{Blank}]+\z/i end
end

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  include ValidatorModule
  def attribute; "email" end
  def valid?(value); value =~ /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i end
end
```

If you think that validation is always done with a single regex, you can go one step further:

```
module ValidatorModule
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    message = options.fetch(:message, I18n.t("errors.attributes.#{attribute}.invalid"))
    record.errors[attribute] << message unless value =~ validation_pattern
  end
end

class NameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  include ValidatorModule
  def attribute; "name" end
  def validation_pattern; /\A[a-z][\w\p{Blank}]+\z/i end
end

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  include ValidatorModule
  def attribute; "email" end
  def validation_pattern; /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep them separate for clarity. The methods are small enough where the obfuscation of the abstraction would make it more, not less, obvious what was going on.

If you start to have 3,4,5,6, or more similar validators where this pattern starts to feel obvious, adding abstraction might make it easier to understand, change, depend on, or remove.

Comment: That's the thing, there are more validators to be extracted in my project. Post title validation, for example..

Comment: How about using the built in ActiveModel format validator? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

Comment: No, I extracted this validator exactly to avoid such situation